Initialization subdocuments models with Typegoose
We're migrating our project from pure Mongoose to Typegoose, overall we're happy but there's one issue that always bothering us.
Let's say we have a simple model:
class Animal {
  @prop()
  public name?: string;
}

const AnimanlModel = getModelForClass(Animal);

Now when we want to create a new item we can just do:
await AnimanlModel.create({ name: 'Kitty' });

But when we are adding a subdocument:
class Animal {
  @prop()
  public name?: string;

  @prop()
  public properties?: Properties;
}

class Properties {
  @prop()
  public hasEaten?: boolean;
}

The initialization become:
const props = new Properties();
props.hasEaten = true;
await AnimanlModel.create({ name: 'Kitty', properties: props });

I know we can use Passthrough Class but it says it's not recomended.
Any idea how we can make the creation easier?

i dont quite understand what the problem here is, how did you do it in pure mongoose? using typegoose shouldnt change how you create new documents.

In Mongoose you would do:
new Animal({ name: 'Kitty', properties: {hasEaten: true}}); but that doesn't compile with Typegoose

you did change it to new AnimalModel for typegoose, right? if yes, what is the exact error, as this should be possible as it is not modified by typegoose.

right, the error is because {hasEaten: true} is not from type Properties

i still dont understand what the issue is, i have created the reproduction script which works perfectly fine: https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose-testing/blob/SO78891263/src/test.ts

We ended up creating a utility class:
class Subdocument<T> {
  constructor(props: Partial<T>) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
  }
}

Then changing our subdocument to extend it:
class Properties extend Subdocument<Properties> {
  @prop()
  public hasEaten?: boolean;
}

And now we can do:
await AnimanlModel.create({ name: 'Kitty', properties: new  Properties({hasEaten: true)});

I someone has a better solution we would love to hear.
